# How to create JSON Data from two tables

Tags: mysql, json, codeigniter, ionic-framework

I have two tables like below:

table: question

```
id ~~ quest
———————————————  
01 ~~ where is the fruit..?
02 ~~ what is the most popular name in the world..?
```

table: choice_answer

```
idq ~~ choice
———————————————  
01  ~~ mango
01  ~~ car
01  ~~ bottle
02 ~~ Jhon
02 ~~ Nina
02 ~~ Michael
```

And the result is:

```
1. "where is the fruit..?"
   * mango
   * car
   * bottle

2. "what is the most popular name in the world..?"
   * Jhon
   * Nina
   * Michael
```

How to make Data JSON ON PHP CodeIgniter?
And How to create view using ng-repeat on IONIC for the result above?

Comment: 1st make array of question and then put loop of question and fire query of ans in this loop then pass your array in `$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($your_array));`

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch data from both tables and make both table's data as two distinct array, and then use json_encode() and feed this function with your two arrays with two name. like:

```
$q = array("q1", "q2");
$a = array("a1", "a2);
echo json_encode(["question" => $q, "content" => $a]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a problem like this. Ionic just did not accept normal echoing JSON.

I suggest to use Rest API from [this](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) if you are using with IONIC. Just follow the sample given in the project.